# Social Security and Death

Tags: united-states, social-security

My father died Jan 12th and no social security payment was posted to his bank account in Jan.& directly deposited on Feb. 4th.  Does that money belong to his estate or will the dept. of social security take it back?  Is social security paid in arrears?

Comment: Was he married at the time of death? Does he have children? If so how many? Social Security has a lot of rules and regulations, you can read more about them here: https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10008.pdf